# How to share GUI parameters between pipeline Jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have many Jenkins pipeline jobs that use the same GUI parameters (defined under 'This project is parameterized' field), for example 'Active Choices Reactive Parameter' that use Groovy script:

[image]

I read about the 'Ez-templates', 'Template project', 'Project Inheritance' plugins but I did not found a way to use them on GUI parameters in pipeline job.

I'm looking for a way to define the parameter in one place and copy/inherit the parameter in other jobs.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Configuration Slicing Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/configurationslicing/)?

You can modify the parameter in all jobs at once.

Comment: I don't want that all the jobs will share the same value for the shared parameter. I'm looking for a way to use the parameter definition in many jobs (instead of redefine the parameter in every job), and to allow the user to choose the value of the parameter in each run of the job.

Comment: But why is it problem for you, if you have to rewrite it in every job? If you want to modify it, it's like modifying only one, shared parameter. The value can be choosen separately in  every job for the parameter.

Comment: From what I see in the plugin, the parameters should be first define in every script and the plugin just allow to change the value of the parameter in all of the job, right?
Also, in the plugin I saw only parameters of type string or bool and not more advance parameter that use groovy script as I needed.